# Распределние памяти

Tags: qt, память

Здравствуйте!
Есть две машины с Windows и Linux(Debian), QT Creator и мое приложение, написанное на Qt. Проблема заключается в том, что на линуксовой машине работающее приложение ест порядка 800 Мб, а запущенный Qt Creator - 4 Гб, в то время как на винде приложение занимает около 30 Мб, а среда 140 Мб. Так как приложение разрабатывалось под Linux, то вопрос уменьшения расхода памяти стоит очень остро. Используется Qt 5.5, на Windows компилятор MinGW. Может кто сталкивался с подобным, подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: для начала хотя бы нужно понять, что Ваше приложение делает. Может оно пережимает видеофайлы. И под виндой ему дали маленькие пятиминутные мультики, а под линуксом часовые 4k.

Comment: Ваш случай слишком часный. Сделайте мониторинг памяти. Следите за тем сколько у вас обьектов и сколько памяти они едят. Возможно у вас есть скрытая утечка памяти.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы. Приложение принимает по сети текстовую информацию от других компьютеров. Память на сохранение входной информации выделяю динамически один раз при создании приложения и потом только перезаписываю, освобождаю при выходе из приложения. Вариант с утечкой я прорабатывала, но во время работы расход памяти не увеличивается, память при запуске приложения такая.

Comment: Создала пустой gui проект, на винде он занимает 12 мб, на линуксе 400 =(. Может дело в сборке Qt под разные ОС? Или можно попробовать изменить ключи qmake при сборке проекта

Comment: А вы случаем на линуксе не дебаг, а на винде релиз версии используете?

Comment: м, а как Вы смотрите занятую память? не путаете ли случайно, занятую память (закоммиченную) и аллоцированную (запрошенную)? Приложение может запросить себе гигабайт памяти, но по факту использовать 1-2 мегабайта. Операционная система будет показывать, что приложение взяло гигабайт.  Но Вы легко запустите  10-20 таких приложений.

Comment: gil9red, нет, сборки сравниваю одинаковые

Comment: KoVadim, сравниваю значения выдаваемые стандартными диспетчерами задач

Comment: хм, действительно под Linux можно запустить множество экземпляров приложения, хотя каждый процесс пишет, что занимает по 900 Мб

Comment: В итоге, действительно, как написал KoVadim, диспетчер задач LXTask показывает запрошенную память - 900 Мб, но реально используется порядка 60 Мб. Спасибо большое за ответы =)